# Does Fluent wait reloads the web page before it polls the DOM every time?

Tags: selenium

I know that fluentWait waits for an element until it reaches the defined time duration and also polls/searches the DOM at a frequency rate that you have mentioned in the implementation. But i am not sure whether it reloads the page every time when it does the DOM polling ?? Can any one help me out please ??

Answer (score 2):

The fluent wait won't reload the DOM.It will just wait for particular time to meet the condition.If the condition doesn't meet then it will again pool for the element.

Comment: adding to it. it can poll the DOM while page is loading.

Answer (score 0):

Answering straight **`No`**, `FluentWait` doesn't reloads the Webpage before each pool of the **`HTML DOM`**.

The documentation of [**`FluentWait`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) clearly depicts the usage details as:

```
   Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

   WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
     public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
       return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
     }
   });
```

Where,

- `withTimeout`: sets how long to wait for the evaluated condition to be true.
- `pollingEvery`: sets how often the condition should be evaluated.
- `ignoring` : exception/exceptions to ignore

As, the associated methods doesn't calls loading of the url or refresh of the current url hence there is no additional reloading of the **`HTML DOM`**.